# extract values as columns into dataframe from same dataframe json string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let have a data frame with json string like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'sno':1, 'values':"[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3}]"},
                   {'sno':2, 'values':"[{'a':4, 'b':5,'c':6}]"}])
```

Need to get the json string column as new columns in the same dataframe. Tried the below code but, getting the error as "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series"

```
df = df.assign(a=lambda x: (json.loads(x['values'])[0]['a']))
```

When we try to use the lambda it should be getting the values for that row only but json.loads(x['values']) actually returning a series and this is causing the error.

Is there any other ways to get this achieved?

Expected dataframe like below

```
sno    a     b     c
------------------------
1      1     2     3
2      4     5     6
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Your input isn't valid, and your "JSON" isn't valid JSON

Comment: @Nick I think the outer single quotes should be double quotes

Comment: @user3625533 please revert (and correct) if I'm wrong

Comment: @mozway the inner single quotes need to be double quotes for it to be JSON

Comment: @Nick yes that's true

Comment: Basically it's unclear what's what...

Comment: Thanks @mozway for editing the dataframe. am getting the 'values' column as string and I need the dataframe with sno, a, b, c columns.

Comment: OK, so as pointed out by Nick, this is not valid JSON. Do you always have only one dictionary per list in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guess correctly, what you want is to extract the value of `a` considering a dictionary in a list.

I would use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) here:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['a'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)[0]['a'])
```

Or:

```
df['a'] = [literal_eval(x)[0]['a'] for x in df['values']]
```

Then it won't matter whether or not you have valid JSON (double quotes and not single quotes).

Output:

```
   sno                  values  a
0    1  [{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3}]  1
1    2  [{'a':4, 'b':5,'c':6}]  4
```

If you need all columns:

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame([literal_eval(x)[0] for x in df['values']],
                           index=df.index))
```

Output:

```
   sno                  values  a  b  c
0    1  [{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3}]  1  2  3
1    2  [{'a':4, 'b':5,'c':6}]  4  5  6
```

Or to overwrite `df` and drop the original `values`:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([literal_eval(x)[0] for x in df.pop('values')],
                          index=df.index))
```

Output:

```
   sno  a  b  c
0    1  1  2  3
1    2  4  5  6
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sno': [1, 2],
                   'values': ["[{'a':1, 'b':2,'c':3}]",
                              "[{'a':4, 'b':5,'c':6}]"]})
```